# virtio is suitable for which type of application

Tags: virtualization, openstack

I know that "virtio enables guests to get high performance network and disk operations". could you please explain for which type of applications we need to use virtio?

Answer (score 0):

As your quoted description implies, you should use `virtio` drivers whenever you want better i/o performance than you would get with fully virtualized devices.

Generally, this means, "all the time", and you should simply use `virtio` drivers in all situations unless there is a specific reason you are unable to do so (for example, you are booting an operating system that does not have `virtio` device drivers available).

Particularly i/o intensive applications will obviously benefit the most from this optimization.